# const {class: clazz} = params;

Tags: javascript

```
const {class: clazz} = params;
```

I just saw this code in a program in Javascript but it feel so weird.

Here, the const "class" is assign the "clazz" variable that comme from the object params.
But why would he use the keyword class that is for define object, doesn't this make conflit with the original class keyword ?

And what could be the advantage of this naming between all possible name, why would he not just use the "clazz" from destructuring ?

I just ask in case this way of doing have a meaning that i don't know.
Thank in advance.

Comment: `class` is the name of the property in `params`. There is no conflict with the `class` keyword. The `class` property is assigned to the `clazz` variable because there would be a conflict there.

Comment: oh so when he do `class: clazz` it mean he assign `class => clazz`  and not the other way around :o ??
it not `class <= clazz`

Comment: [Correct](https://jsbin.com/tipixir/edit?js,console)

Comment: ohhhh ok, thank you very mush :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here, the const "class" is assign the "clazz" variable that comme from the object params.

No. You have that backwards.

The `class` property of `params` is assigned to the constant `clazz` (precisely *because* it would otherwise clash with the `class` keyword)

This throws an error:

```js
const params = {
    class: 12345
}

const { class } = params;
```

This does not:

```js
const params = {
    class: 12345
};

const { class: clazz } = params;

console.log(clazz);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at an [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

`class` exists on the `params` object. Since it's a objects property, there's no collision with the js class keyword.

Consider this simple example:

```js
const params = { class: 'test', somethinguseless: 'ok' };
const {class: clazz} = params;
console.log(clazz);
```

Comment: ohh ok, yeah i miss up the assignation order ><, thanks